# How to correctly render info to handlebars template

Tags: express, webpack, express-handlebars

Rendering information from my controller only passes information through to the partials included on the template.

Here is how I go about it in my login controller. After I check password and username provided I send two objects to the dashboard template that I would like to render to the page

```
res.render(path.join(DIST_DIR, 'dashboard.hbs'), { 
                                    user,
                                    company
                                });
```

I can log this info and can see that it exists and it also renders out in the partials that included on dashboard.hsb, but it seems that dashboard itself is not getting the data.

My webpack setup

```
{
                // Loads the javacript into html template provided.
                // Entry point is set below in HtmlWebPackPlugin in Plugins 
                test: /\.hbs$/,
                loader: 'handlebars-loader',
                query: {
                    partialDirs: [
                        path.join(__dirname, './src/views/partials')
                    ],
                    helperDirs: [
                        path.join(__dirname, './src/helpers')
                    ]
                }
            },
```

```
new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            filename: 'dashboard.hbs',
            title: 'Dashboard',
            chunks: ['dashboard', 'dashboard~login', 'vendors~dashboard', 'vendors~dashboard~login'],
            template: 'src/views/index/dashboard.hbs',
            excludeChunks: ['server']
        }),
```

So the page renders fine and the user information that I try to pass does show up in the partials (used by dashboard layout), but the information for the user that I want to display in the body of dashboard.hbs is always blank. I seems that information is not passed to this template.

Where am I going wrong? I would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong loader. Instead of using handlebars-loader, I updated the code to use the html-loader

```
{
                // Loads the javacript into html template provided.
                // Entry point is set below in HtmlWebPackPlugin in Plugins 
                test: /\.hbs$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                query: {
                    partialDirs: [
                        path.join(__dirname, './src/views/partials')
                    ],
                    helperDirs: [
                        path.join(__dirname, './src/helpers')
                    ]
                }
            },
```

And now everything works as expected. Hope this helps someone else down the line